# XML Parsing in iPhone not getting any response

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I need to call an XML file from a WCF Service and parse the content of XML in iPhone. I'm able to call the service URL but when parsing using NSXMLParser, I couldn't get a patricular attribute value in XML. I'm using a ViewController application in XCode.

My XML file is like this:

```
<GetCompanyResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DomainModel" 
 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    
 <CompanyList>
    <Company>
      <Id>b9ca2e32-ce88-4d72-99ce-9bc592511e85</Id>
    </Company>
 </CompanyList>




   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.107:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/IServices/

        AppointmentService/json/GetCompany";
        NSURL *jsonUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

        [parser parse];
        [parser release];  

        - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
         namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:
         (NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
         {

           if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Company"]) {
            NSString *name=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Id"];

        }
        }
```

But when I check for the value in 'name' it is returning nil. I don't know what's wrong. What should I change? How can I get the value of the ID attribute?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id is not attribute of the name. Put code in didEndElement:
define strVal  NSString in .h;

```
Inside found character:
{
   strVal=string;
}

Inside parserDidEndElement method:
     {

       if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"]) {
        NSString *name=strVal;

    }
    }
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Hey VXtreme still its returning nil value for Id ..I have written this:parser didStartElement{if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"]) {
       NSString *name=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Id"];            
    }parser foundCharacters:{ 
    strVal=string;
       }
parser didEndElement{if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"]) {
        NSString *name=strVal;} Still it is returning nil value ..Can u please tell me where I'm I going wrong?

Comment: firstly u don't have to write anything inside didStartElement .secondly have you defined strVal in .h file? check the log inside found character .Print value after  NSString *name=strVal; statement and see are you getting something ?

Comment: Yes I have defined strVal in .h file.ok I have removed the code in didStartElement.Eventhough i couldnot get .If I see the console area the value for name is by checkin the output area is :Printing description of name:
(gdb)

Comment: Actually Id is GUID datatype;Then how should I consume it ?

Comment: as all the xml in the string format You will get Id also in the string format

Comment: but I m unable to get it...Please help

Comment: Now we will go step-by-step first check your xml response is valid or not using some online xml validator.If your xml is same as above then i don't thing it is valid

Comment: Yes I have checked using xml validator and I got this error:"Content is not allowed in prolog."
At this line :This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.How should I get a particular version of XML ?

Comment: your xml should be like :<?xml version="1.0" ?> 

 <CompanyList>
    <Company>
      <Id>b9ca2e32-ce88-4d72-99ce-9bc592511e85</Id>
    </Company>
 </CompanyList>

Comment: I checked it in internet explorer and getting  like this :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <GetCompanyResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><CompanyList>
    <Company>
      <Id>b9ca2e32-ce88-4d72-99ce-9bc592511e85</Id>
    </Company>
 </CompanyList>
  </GetCompanyResponse> .I think its perfect ..I got the error when I tested it with chrome.

Comment: Hey Thank u VXtreme for ur help..I got it working ...Actually I did not define the parameter Id in .h file...Thanks a lot again